# Difference between (plain) Classworlds and Plexus Classworlds?

Tags: maven-2, plexus

Can anyone please explain the difference between [plexus-classworlds](http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-classworlds/) and [(plain) classworlds](http://classworlds.codehaus.org/)?

These two are confusing and can't see the difference. Plexus classworlds contains almost no description. Apparently, a maven-based Java project uses both, I don't understand why.

Is it possible to replace classworlds with plexus-classworlds without much hassle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm gonna answer that, even though the question is so old...

classworlds was migrated to plexus-classworlds, but the documentation on the site doesn't seem to keep up with that... the best docs I've seen was on classworlds 1.1-SNAPSHOT, although the current is plexus-classworlds 2.4.1-SNAPSHOT, and there is hardly any doc there.

if you look at plexus-classworlds, you can also see the original org.codehaus.classworlds package, with class comments like this:

> A compatibility wrapper for org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher provided for legacy code

which means that they thought about migration, but of course nothing replaces a thorough test.